# call function with error: too few arguments to function ‘quicksort’

Tags: c

In this program, I want to sort a list, according to price, and then i use a quick sort to sort the list, in the quick sort, I used the compare of comp_on_price, and then call the quick sort at interface. However, when I run it, it comes up with compile error of too few argument.
Does there have anything to do with the calling method?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *fp;

typedef struct book{
    double rating;
    double price;
    double relevance;
    int ID;
}B;

B *list;

int read_file(char* infile, int N)
{
    int c;
    if((fp=fopen(infile, "rb")))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%*s\t%*s\t%*s\t%*s\n");
        c=0;
        while((!feof(fp))&&(c<N))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%d\n", &list[c].rating, &list[c].price, &list[c].relevance, &list[c].ID);
            c++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s did not open. Exiting.\n",infile);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return(c);
}

int comp_on_price(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if ((*(B *)a).price < (*(B *)b).price)
        return 1;
    else if ((*(B *)a).price > (*(B *)b).price)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void quicksort(int x[10],int first, int last, int(*comp_on_price)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int pivot,j,temp,i;
    if(first<last)
    {
        pivot=first;
        i=first;
        j=last;

        while(i<j)
        {
            while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
            i++;
            while(x[j]>x[pivot])
            j--;
            if(i<j){
                temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=temp;
            }
        }/* while*/

        temp=x[pivot];
        x[pivot]=x[j];
        x[j]=temp;
        quicksort(x,first,j-1);
        quicksort(x,j+1,last);
    }
}

void user_interface(int N)
{
    // For Part 1 this function calls the sort function to sort on Price only
    comp_on_price(N);

    // For Part 2 this function
    // (1) asks the user if they would like to sort their search results
    // (2) asks for the most important field (or key), the next most etc
    // (3) calls your sort function
}

void print_results(int N)
{
    int i;
    if((fp=fopen("top20.txt","w")))
    {
        for(i=N-1;i>=N-20;i--)
        {
            printf("%g %g %g %d\n", list[i].rating, list[i].price, list[i].relevance, list[i].ID);
            fprintf(fp, "%g %g %g %d\n", list[i].rating, list[i].price, list[i].relevance, list[i].ID);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Trouble opening output file top20.txt\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N;

    if(argc!=3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "./exec <input_size> <filename>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    N=atoi(argv[1]);

    list = (B *)malloc(N*sizeof(B));

    N=read_file(argv[2], N);

    user_interface(N);

    print_results(N);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your code in order to make it readable.

Comment: Have you heard of `qsort()`? It is part of C standard since C89.

Comment: @qrdl I thing he just wants to implement it by himself.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Maybe, but I've seen people implementing quicksort just because they didn't know about standard library function, thus was my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
quicksort(x,first,j-1);
```

If you take a look at your `quicksort` function declaration, you'll see it has 4 and not 3 parameters. The last parameter is a pointer to a comparison function.

You should call it like this:

```
quicksort(x, first, j-1, comp_on_price);
```

Comment: I added the comp_on_price, however, the problems still occurs, I think is it something to do with my interface argument?

Comment: @StevenLiu what other error message do you get if you add the fourth argument to your function call?

Comment: And as noted in another answer if you don't use an argument in an function, there is no need to add it to the list of parameters in your function.

Answer (score 1):

your function

```
void quicksort(int x[10],int first, int last,int(*comp_on_price)(const void *, const void     *))
```

has 4 input parameter and the last one is a pointer to a function. you can remove it because you did not use it this function